# How to use Weex ios sdk pragma #define WX_EXPORT_METHOD(method) in swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, weex

I am using Weex ios sdk.
For exposing js method there is a pragma

```
#define WX_EXPORT_METHOD(method)
```

But this pragma is accessible in objective C file only.
I need to use this in swift file.

Is there any way to do so ?

Comment: Check out https://weex.incubator.apache.org/guide/extend-module-using-swift.html

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution of your work is to create Objective-c Bridging header look this :

https://github.com/apache/incubator-weex-site/blob/master/source/cn/guide/extend-module-using-swift.md

Comment: This is exposing via Objective C file. I want to use them directly in swift file.